# Creating Leap Year program (Century included)

Tags: java, leap-year

I am in my first year so I am really a newbie and we have homework which is –

> By definition a leap year is any year that is divisible by 4. However if a year is a century year it is only a leap year if it is divisible by 400.  Write a Java program that will input a year and determine if the year is leap year of not.

Also, since a century year is not known, I have to calculate it also basing from the entered year. I have read an answer online which I think is correct – getting the first 2 digits of the year then add 1.

Can I use the if/else only?

I don’t know how to do this. Submission is a day after today. Please help!

My code looks like this and I know that it lacks the century year.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class leapyear
{
        public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int year, centuryyear;
        System.out.print("Please enter a year: ");
        year = in.nextInt();

        if ((year % 4 == 0) && centuryyear % 400 == 0)
            {
            System.out.println(year + " Is a Leap Year");
            year++;
            }   
        else
            {
            System.out.println(year + " Is not a leap year");
            year++;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't actually ask a question

Comment: hi! I only need my homework to be done and my code is incomplete. (no Century year)

Comment: Are you trying to let us do your homework? :-)

Comment: with your help to complete it. I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a seperate "century year" variable.  You just need to test the year to see if it meets the criteria.  The criteria:

Divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100 unless also divisible by 400

You already know how to use % to test for these conditions so let's look at them individually:

Year divisible by 4 would be: year % 4 == 0

Not divisible by 100 would be: year % 100 != 0

But divisible by 400 would be: year % 400 == 0

So we need the first expression AND the second expression OR the third expression:

```
if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)
```

Comment: thank you! I have already done it and it's now working... Actually, we have 20 homework and our teacher have not taught us well on how to do these especially that we cannot test it during discussion as it was only a lecture (we are not at the laboratory wherein we can practice at the same time). us.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that, what I did was only clicking the vote up... now I know what's that for... done now! :)

Comment: Um, but you did it on a different answer.  If that was what you used, that's fine.  If you used mine, click on the check next to this answer.

Comment: Looks like you clicked on mine then off of it again.

Comment: yes, I used what you have answered. The AND and OR. Also, I have already clicked the check icon next to this.

Comment: yes because after clicking it, it's color changes to green but after reloading it, it appears that I haven't clicked on it.. why is that?

Comment: Your check is on the answer above this one.  You clicked on this one, then off of it to the one above it.

Comment: Does that mean that I should only check one?

Comment: Yes, you can only accept one answer.  Pick the one that you actually used.

Comment: There you go.  Thank you.

Comment: I do.  Thanks again.  Glad I could help you.

Comment: yes.. I should be the one thanking you....I have tagged you with my other program which I'm stuck of.. I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I won't do your homework for you. I would suggest you first break the problem down logically before you try and code it up.

Write the conditions in English first and then try and write the code to match, something like:

> it is a leap year if: the year is divisible by 4 **unless** it is also divisible by 100 **unless**.... etc etc

Once written down like that it might make the logic easier to understand and then easier to codeify.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about the following hints:

1. `year % 4 == 0` only means that year is a leap year if it is no century year.
2. The variable `centuryyear` is useless and can be removed from your program.
3. A year is a century year if it is divisible by 100.
4. Do you know the OR operator `||`?

Then do it as advised by Sam Holder.

Comment: yes I know the OR operator but haven't tried using it. Thank your for your answers and suggestions.. I appreciate it so much.. It is now very late here but I need to make this thing work before going to bed... Thanks guys really! Million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the if/else only?

Yes, you can. One suggestion. You may use a nested `if~else` blocks. There is no reason you have to find just a single and right `if` condition.

```
if (...) {
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course you can use `if~else if` instead of nested `if~else`.

```
if (... && ...) {
    ...
} else if (... && ...) {
    ...
}
```

At last this is also equivalent (a single but nested if condition):

```
if ((... && ...) || (... && ...)) {
    ...
}
```